# AOSP system service getting avc denied error while trying to add service from SystemServer

Tags: android, android-source, system-services

Hi I am adding my koushikservice in aospCodebase/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java like this

```
KoushikService koushikservice = null;
            try{
                traceBeginAndSlog("KOUSHIK_SERVICE adding trace");
                koushikservice = new KoushikService(mSystemContext);
                ServiceManager.addService(Context.KOUSHIK_SERVICE,koushikservice);
            }catch(Throwable e){
                Slog.e(TAG, "Starting KOUSHIK_SERVICE failed!!! ", e);
            }
            traceEnd();
```

I am getting "KOUSHIK_SERVICE adding trace" log but then getting avc denied. Please let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add SELinux rules to allow that service. By default SELinux is deny unless explicitly allowed.

Your easiest way forward to do this would be to compare to an existing service and rules for that.

Otherise based on what I added for a service on my case, and assuming that value of `Context.KOUSHIK_SERVICE = "koushik"` here's roughly what should be added :

File: **koushik.te**

```
type koushik, domain;
```

In file **service_contexts**, add:

```
koushik                    u:object_r:koushik_service:s0
```

In file **service.te**  add:

```
type koushik_service,  service_manager_type;
```

In file **system_server.te**, add:

```
add_service(system_server,koushik_service)
```

Lastly, if you want to allow a domain to find and use your service, for example from **platform_app**, you add in **platform_app.te**:

```
allow platform_app koushik_service:service_manager find;
```

Comment: Glad to hear that problem got solved . Don't forget to accept the answer